# Why cant std::string take spaces in user input?

Tags: c++, string, tokenize, spaces

Straight to the problem:

This code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string string = "9 9";
    std::cout << string;
    return 0;
}
```

returns `9 9` as output.

Yet, when inputting `9 9` to this code,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string string;
    std::cin >> string;
    std::cout << string;
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs `9`. Why does this happen?

I guess it has to do with the space, but is there any way to avoid this? I must say space is the only valid separation between numbers.

Answer (score 7):

`std::cin` takes one word at a time. To take the whole line you would need to use `getline()` function.

Usage: 
`std::getline (std::cin,name);`

Your case: This should work when you `include <string>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string MyString;
    std::getline (std::cin, MyString);
    std::cout << MyString;
    return 0;
}
```

Advice: Don't you ever use `using namespace std;` anymore. Also, use proper variable names.

Comment: `operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)` reads one word at a time. What `std::cin` reads depends upon what function you pass it to.

Comment: @ben very useful comment

Comment: In simpler terms: `std::cin` does _not_ read "one word at a time". It is just a stream object representing the standard input stream. You could very well read all characters available from `std::cin`, including spaces, until, _e.g._, an eof is detected.

Comment: @FirstStep why should you not use "using namespace std" if that is the only name space you are using, why is it bad? That's kinda a big claim for me, I could see that being an issue in a template since you don't know how it will be used. But in main that is a problem?

Comment: @cam it is completely fine to use here and/or for simple programs and many programmers are using it in big programs but it is just a good practice to know how, why and when to use it. here is a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

The standard library overload<sup>†</sup> of the **input operator `>>`** taking an `std::istream` and a `std::string` as parameters, is designed to read characters from the stream into the `std::string` object *until* a delimiter i found, and then return the altered stream (for further reads).

All whitespace characters are by default recognized as delimiters, *e.g.* in most implementations, , `\t`, and `\n` (the true meaning of whitespace is defined by the locale's `ctype` facet).

The purpose of this design is for the usage of the input operator as a tokenizer of input data, *e.g.*:

```
std::istringstream input_stream{"apple banana pear"};

std::string token;
while (input_stream >> token) {
    // Token per iteration is: "apple", "banana", and "pear".
}
```

Here `input_stream >> token` is equivalent to the call `std::operator>>(input_stream, token)` which will read characters up until a delimiter into `token`, and then return the stream object `input_stream`. The returned stream object is finally checked as a `bool` in the `while` clause, which basically returns `!input_stream.fail()` (see [`std::basic_ios::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)).

If what you need is to read characters until a linebreak or end-of-file is detected then use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

If you want to read N characters from the stream then use, *e.g.*, [`std::basic_istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

---

#### Reference:

<sup>†</sup>http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Comment: It reads until whitespace (ignoring EOF and `width`), where "whitespace" is defined by the locale's ctype facet.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is an extraction stream object whose extraction behavior is dependent on the `>>` operator overload used. (Thanks Ben)

For C-style strings, `std::string` and its variants; it's operator overload only extracts one "word" (non-delimited sequence of characters) at a time.

To get an entire line of characters, you would use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Note: The default delimiters is dependent on your default locale, for `en_us.utf8` it includes but not limited to, any whitespace(`" "`), tab(`"\t"`), and newline(`"\n"`) encountered

Comment: Not sure what a *"formatted extraction stream object"* is, but the behavior is a characteristic of the operator function. It is not specific to the object.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, True... modified, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen? I guess it has to do with the space, but is
>   there any way to avoid this? I must say space is the only valid
>   separation between numbers.

The input operators ignore whitespace by default ( blank, tab, newline, formfeed and carriage return)!

You can use `std::getline` to read until newline (by default):

```
std::getline(std::cin, string);
```

Answer (score 0):

after writing **using name space std** : don't use **std::cin** somrthing like this.